# error while unit testing angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-controller

Can someone help me solve this. Tried to create a single page app using angular in front end and node in the back end.
Tried to install karma and jasmine and wrote a simple test spec to check the title of the controller. The app works fine and is routing fine. But when I try to do unit testing using jasmine. It throws the following error and the test suite fails. Please help me find out what went wrong.

karma start karma.conf.js
30 10 2017 11:36:16.490:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
30 10 2017 11:36:16.507:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
30 10 2017 11:36:16.508:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
30 10 2017 11:36:16.542:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
30 10 2017 11:36:19.563:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket ZViNyPVeq1YwHHl-AAAA with id 30996953
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) testing AngularJS testing controllers should initialize title FAILED
        C:/Users/Public/projects/hospital_angularjs/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4958:53
        forEach@C:/Users/Public/projects/hospital_angularjs/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:410:24
        loadModules@C:/Users/Public/projects/hospital_angularjs/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4917:12
        createInjector@C:/Users/Public/projects/hospital_angularjs/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4839:30
        WorkFn@C:/Users/Public/projects/hospital_angularjs/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3172:60
        inject@C:/Users/Public/projects/hospital_angularjs/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3152:46
        unit/testingunitspec.js:9:19
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:162:17
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0 secs / 0.015 secs)

The main.js file is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',["ngRoute"]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope){
    $scope.title = "Welcome!";
});
```

My testSpec.js file is

```
describe('testing AngularJS', function(){
beforeEach(module('myApp'));

describe('testing controllers', function() {

    it('should initialize title', function() {
        var scope = {};
        var ctrl;
        inject(function($controller) {
            ctrl = $controller('myCtrl', {$scope:scope});
        });
        expect(scope.title).toBeDefined();
        expect(scope.title).toBe('Welcome!');
    });
});
```

});

Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: checked the above link. I am unable to solve the error. It says "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scope.title') in unit/testingunitspec.js (line 12)"